# Use Fix Command (fc) with sublime text

Tags: bash, sublime-text

I want to make an alias for fixing my previous commands easily.

Using `alias fix="fc -e nano"` works, but I'd love to use sublime text with this. However, using `fc -e subl` only brings a blank editor.

I understand that nano only opens up `/tmp/bash-fc.PUKKW8`. I can force sublime text to open this file manually, but can't figure out a way to open it through `fc`. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

set the `FCEDIT` variable:

```
FCEDIT="subl -w"
fc
```

Add it in your `~/.bashrc` to enable autostart.

Comment: This has the same effect as `fc -e subl`.
I think this is due to the fact that subl starts in the background.

Comment: Fixed it!
I will accept your answer if you change it to `fc -e "subl -w"`!